# Execute 3 commands using fork

Tags: fork

In short, I need to execute 3 commands, `mkdir`, `chdir` and `pwd` using `fork`.

The situation: I have a parent process that forks into a child process that executes `mkdir`.

The question: Will that child process become a parent of another child process that executes `chdir`?

I really hope you understand my question.

Comment: There isn't enough here to go on. What environment? What implementation of fork? Maybe show some code. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

*Will that child process become a parent of another child process that executes `chdir`?*

It depends on how you write your code.If parent creates 3 children and each child exit after executing command then child can't be parent.

**example:**

```
pid_t kid;
int I = 0;
int status;
for (I = 0; I< 3; I++) {
       kid = fork();
       if (-1 == kid) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
       } else if (0 == kid) {
           // execute command
            exit(0);
      }
}
while (wait(&status) != -1)
exit(0);
```

If parent creates a child and wait for it. Child executes a command and later creates another child then child elder child can be parent.

**example:**

```
pid_t kid;
int I = 0;
int status;
int last_child = 2;
for (I = 0; I < 3; I++) {
       kid = fork();
       if (-1 == kid) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
       } else if (0 == kid) {
           // execute command
           if (I == last_child)
            exit(0);
      }
      // parent will wait here
      wait(&status);
}
exit(0);
```

Hope it helps.